# How to Make a Grid of Pixels

Tags: java

I am trying to create a grid (100 x 80) of pixels that all start out with no set color. Does anyone know how to do this? Please include any imports I would need and thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try already? What API/classes are you using?

Comment: Swing? Android? Spring-MVC (why not)? (...) I guess one can assume you talk about Swing here, but it is better to be specific.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want to with those pixels.

Comment: `int[] somePixels = new int[100 * 80];` Not helpful? Then be more specific!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tutorial that can teach you how to do this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/  This is a snippet from it that is similar to what you're trying to do:

```
package painting;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
        SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250,200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        // Draw Text
        g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    }  
}
```